# $\langle x,x_n\rangle \leq \|x_n\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products, weak-convergence

I am wondering if we have that $x_n\to x$ weakly, is it then true that $\langle x,x_n\rangle \leq \|x_n\|$, and why?

Comment: If $x_n = x$ this would imply $\|x\|^2 = \langle x,x_n \rangle \le \|x\|$.

Comment: But $x_n$ is the limit of x, so how can we say that $x_n=x$?

Comment: Do you mean $x$ is the limit of $x_n$?

Comment: *In the particular case that $\{x_n\}$ is a constant sequence with $x_n = x$ for all $n$* this would imply $\|x\|^2 = \langle x,x_n \rangle \le \|x\|$.

Comment: yeah I mean that x is the limit of $x_n$

Answer (score 2):

For me it is wrong.

On $\mathbb{R}$ take $x=2$ and $x_n = 2- \frac{1}{n}$.

Then $\langle x,x_n\rangle = 2\left(2- \frac{1}{n}\right)$, $\| x_n\|=2- \frac{1}{n} < 2\left(2- \frac{1}{n}\right)$

and of course $x_n \to x$ strongly so a fortiori weakly.